# How do I nicely instantiate an array of specific numbers in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I know with strings its as simple as this:

```
string_array = %w(list of strings)
```

but is there something similar for integers?

```
number_array = %i(1 2 3)
```

Comment: yes, `number_array = [1, 2, 3]`

Comment: @Sergio, I think an expression without commas is wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no short-hand for this because you can approach it one of two ways:

```
number_array = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

That's the conventional approach. A `%w` approach looks like this:

```
number_array = %w[ 1 2 3 ].map(&:to_i)
```

Either way is equivalent but the former is slightly more efficient if you're doing this very frequently.

Comment: "there's no short-hand because..." - that's a non-existing causal relationship there :)

Comment: These things are usually introduced where there's a compelling use case. `%i` was adopted more recently because making lists of symbols was common enough it warranted a short-hand. I'm not sure integers fall in the same camp here.

Comment: I think you are right. Seems strange as Ruby otherwise has a shorthand for everything... I went through %a through %z and none produce number arrays. The %i one from my example interestingly produces an array of symbols: %i[1 2 3] == [:"1", :"2", :"3"]

Comment: @oMiKeY The savings in terms of keystrokes and characters is pretty marginal, so it's unlikely to become a thing, but you never know. `%d` and `%f` *could* be useful.

Comment: @tadman: yes-yes, I was just hinting that word "because" here conveys wrong information. Before we had `%i` we also could create symbol arrays in different ways, yet `%i` became a thing. `s/because/but/` :) [/style-police-mode-off]

Comment: I think it would be very useful, at least as useful as string arrays. I think comma separated will have to do for now, but I am lazy, you know?`

Comment: If you find yourself dong this a lot you can always extend Array to have something like `as_i` on the end that does the `map(&:to_i)` for you. Then again, if you have a lot of numerical lists like this maybe you should dump them in a YAML or JSON config file.

Comment: I can see how #2 could be a convenient at times, such as when cutting and pasting tables of integers. For example, `%w| 1 2 3\n   4 5 6\n   7 8 9\n |.map(&:to_i) #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] `.